# Count mysql entries with same value in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

In mysql, I have the following information:

```
Article_Name   Category_ID
-------------  -----------
Penguins            20
Lions               20
Tigers              20
Electricity         21
Power Plants        21
Buddhism            22
```

I want to count the number of articles, or I guess you call them "entries", with the Category_ID "20". Is there a function php function I can call to find the number of articles with Category_ID "20"?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(Article_Name) FROM yourTable WHERE Category_ID = 20
```